# Return correct client for WSDL based on condition - same client but different namespace

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I have two WSDL files. They are almost identical, except namespace and endpoint.
First one point to test system, second to production.
TEST - https://sandbox.dhl24.com.pl/webapi2.html
PRODUCTION - https://dhl24.com.pl/webapi2.html

No I'd like to switch from TEST to PRODUCTION based on condition - have factory that would return client for TEST or PRODUCTION.
Changing endpoint didn't help because namespace in generated `Reference.cs` is different:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="https://sandbox.dhl24.com.pl/webapi2/provider/service.html?ws=1", ConfigurationName="TEST.DHL24WebapiPort")]
```

and

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="https://dhl24.com.pl/webapi2/provider/service.html?ws=1", ConfigurationName="PRODUCTION.DHL24WebapiPort")]
```

I'm aware I can reconfigure Service Reference using Visual Studio (right click -> Configure Service Reference...) but I would like to use same code for both systems and configure everything in config file.

I know that I can use conditional compilation symbols, but this excludes ability to switch service from config file.

Is there an option to change namespace of service?

I can add both services to project (in different namespaces) but they don't have anything common, so I will have to create interface and all necessary common classes and manually edit both Reference.cs files.

Ideally both services wold have same namespace but different endpoint, but I can't do that because I'm not creator of webservice.