# Environment dependent namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am consuming a third party webservice in C#.net and I have generated a reference to it using the wsdl provided. Now, the third party has different environments and the namespaces in each are depending on the environment eg:

```
prod https://prod.company.net/api/B2b/
staging: https://stage.company.net/api/B2b/
dev : https://dev.company.net/api/B2b/
```

The reference that I had generated was based on the wsdl in staging and now I need to modify my Reference.cs to the production namespace. Is there a way to avoid this modification to Reference.cs everytime I deploy to either production or staging/dev.

TL;DR Different namespaces in each environment are giving me nightmares.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to manage multiple Service References in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330435/best-way-to-manage-multiple-service-references-in-net)

Comment: If that's the only difference between them then a powershell step in your release to do a search and replace should do the trick.

Comment: That's what I have been doing... but it gets annoying after a while. I do think that the approach by third party is not the correct way to define namespace.

Comment: Are you sure it is the namespaces that differ, and not the service URLs? It's highly unusual to have a different namespace per environment.

Comment: Exactly my dilemma. If the service URL's were different, I could easily handle them by having a setting in the config file for different environments and point to appropriate URL.

Comment: here is a similar question that never got an answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648642/return-correct-client-for-wsdl-based-on-condition-same-client-but-different-na